# How many rounds of the monopoly table occur per monopoly match?

Tags: monopoly

I am trying to produce research regarding monopoly and I want to know  where I could find out how many rounds of the monopoly table occur per monopoly match. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know if you get a clear answer to this.   Monopoly does not have a fixed number of rounds and it is going to vary depending on player count, the players and if they are using and game extending house rules.

Comment: While I agree this is a bit broad right now, stats from some high level tournaments like the Monopoly World Championships might be interesting, although I don't know how many of those games actually play to conclusion and how many end up with people resigning when they are obviously going to lose.

Comment: The MWC records won't be useful to answer this question, as most matches are ended on time, not by having a winner. The 2015 prelims had 21 games of which 6 had a winner. And those will only give you stats for games that had few enough rounds to produces a winner in a short time. Plus (as you hint at) the adjustments in play strategy players will make when faced with time limits will render the results not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

According to one source that provides Monopoly statistics, it is about **30 turns per player**.

[Source](https://ideas.ted.com/heres-how-to-win-at-monopoly-according-to-math-experts/):

> Since the average game of Monopoly takes about 30 turns per competitor[...]

Unfortunately they don't provide more detailed analysis showing the numbers used in calculating this average number of turns, but the page does include specific statistics to suggest that this number is more than just a guess.